# Merging Dataframes in R Excluding Rows

Tags: r

Sorry if this is terribly formatted, I'm still getting used to this site and learning how to do things in R. Sorry if this is an obvious question also, but I tried a lot of different things and looked up similar questions and answers and still couldn't figure this out :(

I want to merge the data.frames (frame1 and frame2) by columns V1 and VB, keeping the rows that match, but excluding the rows that don't the get something like frame3.

frame1

```
V1    V2
A     1a
B     2a
C     3a
D     4a
```

frame2

```
VA    VB    VC
1     A     15
2     B     14
3     C     13
4     AA    12
5     BB    11
6     D     10
```

frame3

```
V1VB   V2    VA    VC
A      1a    1     15
B      2a    2     14
C      3a    3     13
D      4a    6     10
```

I tried:

```
test <- merge(frame1, frame2, by.x='V1',by.y='VB',all=FALSE)
test
```

But I'm not getting my intended result.

Thank-you for all your help!

Comment: remove **all = FALSE**

Comment: I guess you need `all.x = TRUE`

Comment: You should look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right/1300618#1300618

Comment: `frame1` and `frame2` have no row or column in common. Name VB => V1 and it should work. See [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-merge-function-with-data-sets-in-r.html) for explenations.